# Check if all bodies are stopped

Tags: cocos2d-x-3.0, chipmunk

I am new to physics engines. I am using Cocos2dx v3.4 with physics engine Chipmunk.
How can I check whether all bodies are stopped or not?

Answer (score 0):

Try method body.isSleeping() during iterating over all bodies.

Link: https://chipmunk-physics.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=1103

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I check if one sprite is stopped:

```
#define STOP_VELOCITY 1.

if (sprite->getPhysicsBody()->getVelocity().x > STOP_VELOCITY || sprite->getPhysicsBody()->getVelocity().x < -STOP_VELOCITY ||
    sprite->getPhysicsBody()->getVelocity().y > STOP_VELOCITY || sprite->getPhysicsBody()->getVelocity().y < -STOP_VELOCITY) {
        return false;
    } else {
        sprite->getPhysicsBody()->setVelocity(Vec2(0,0));
        return true;
    }
}
```